# Epicontacts in R - Temporal Axis Error: "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns"

Tags: r

I have a problem with the x_axis when I try to do a temporal axis om the transmission chain.

This error shows:

```
"Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns"
```

Example code:

```
library(outbreaks)
library(epicontacts)

head(mers_korea_2015[[1]])
head(mers_korea_2015[[2]])

x <- make_epicontacts(linelist=mers_korea_2015[[1]],
contacts = mers_korea_2015[[2]],
directed=TRUE)

vis_epicontacts(x, x_axis = "dt_onset", thin = FALSE)
```

How do I solve this?

I have updated epicontacts, and it still dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! There were a bug, and it´s fixed now. A new installation may be needed if you have problem.

For more information, se discussion here:
https://github.com/reconhub/epicontacts/issues/130